# File input output question with Inputstreamreader

Tags: java, android

I made an android app which writes to a file in an activity. 
The writing to file, it works like a charm:

```
FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("myfeeds.txt",
                    MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
         OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
         osw.write(file);
         osw.flush();
         osw.close();
```

But when I want to read it back from another acivity it can't find the file...the file exists I checked with DDMS file explorer.
Reading file contents:

```
         FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("myfeeds.txt");    // cant find file
         InputSource input = new InputSource(fis);
         xr.setContentHandler(this);
         xr.parse(input);
```

What is the correct location to my file?

Comment: Have you checked the Android documentation about [internal and external file storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `openFileInput` to get FileInputStream object for those files which are written using openFileOutputStream

use the following code

```
FileInputStream fiss = openFileInput("myfeeds.txt");
InputSource input = new InputSource(fis);
         xr.setContentHandler(this);
         xr.parse(input);
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response... openFileInput is not recognised, so using the above code,I worked around it out...

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
openFileInput( String name )
```

to read your file.

Regards,
 STéphane